# Send form with select value choice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select information returned as an array with the element name and id .

I need that when the select is sent, is made with the identifier of the chosen option.

But for a logical reason , I need in the select the item name is displayed, and to show the identifier would be meaningless.

I tried the following:

```
$('#selectCategory').on('change', function () {
    var optionSelect = $(this).val();
    $.post("{{path('playlist_category') }}", {category: optionSelect}, 
    function (filterContent) {
        $('#playlist_content_name').empty(); 
        for (var content in filterContent.category_result) {
            var id = filterContent.category_result[content].id;
            var name = filterContent.category_result[content].name;
            console.log(name);
            console.log(id);
            $('#playlist_content_name').append('<option value"'+ id +'">' + name + '</option>'); 
        }
    }, 'json');
});
```

But the form is submitted with the name of the select , not the ID.

**EDIT:**

This work.

Forget to sign = in the option value.

```
$('#playlist_content_name').append('<option value="' + id +'">' + name + '</option>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...
var name = filterContent.category_result[content].name;

if(filterContent.category_result[content].nodeName === 'select') {
    name = filterContent.category_result[content].value;
}
```

This will grab the select box value but you will need to check, you should be able to drop this in below `var name....` without needing to change anything.

Comment: I do not understand where I should put that line of code.

Comment: This work:

`$('#playlist_content_name').append('<option value="'+id+'">' + name + '</option>');`

My problem was that I needed a sign '=' in option value.. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, don't forget to update your example so other people can learn from this question too.